# What is type context?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm currently stuck to understand which variables are considered to be local, and which are global.

In [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) we can read that:

`Global variables are variables that are defined outside of any function, method, closure, or type context.`

I'm guessing that: variables defined in type context `==` type/instance variables defined inside class/struct?

For example:

```
var foo = "foo" // global variable

class Foobar {
  static var foo = "foo" // local variable -> declared inside Foobar type context
  var bar = "bar" // local variable -> declared inside Foobar type context

  func foobar() {
    var foo = "" // local variable -> declared inside method
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, variables defined inside class context become either instance variables or type variables.cVariables defined inside the context of a function, method, or a closure become local variables.

A declaration of a global variable must be at the top level, outside of classes, functions, and so on.

Comment: dashblinkenlight@can you update your answer with your comments in matDobek's code.So that it will become more clear.